# Should I preload a large image that's above the fold?

Tags: html, performance, optimization, preloading

I'm excited about the `rel="preload"` property, because it looks like it can help speed up page render times.

The use case is a web page with a large image above the fold. Right now, Chrome doesn't start downloading the image until after fetching jQuery (a fairly heavy file). With preloading enabled, they download in parallel.

But I'm reading conflicting reports about whether I should use `preload` for things that are in visible HTML elements elsewhere (as opposed to things made visible by user interaction, like a dropdown menu).

[This post](https://jack.ofspades.com/prefetching-preloading-and-prerendering-content-with-html/index.html) seems to recommend not preloading:

> When not to use preloading:
>
> - *When the asset is referred to somewhere else on the same page*.
> - When you're not sure the user will actually require that asset. Like on a page visitors only go to 3% of the time.

While [this one](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf) seems to indicate it was really helpful for a similar situation on the Financial Times website:

> When the Financial Times introduced a Link preload header to their site, they shaved 1 second off the time it took to display the masthead image...

So which is it? Should I provide an early "hint" to display the always-shown, above-the-fold image? Or should I just let the browser get to it in the usual order?

Comment: A lot of times it is more important the perceived loading time than the real one. Depending on the content, sometimes you will expect to have the text ready sooner, or the interaction available sooner, sometimes the image... You should try it and see how it feels. One concrete case I remember: a white loading screen for 6-7 seconds was unacceptable, but 9-10 seconds with a little logo and loading animation was totally ok.

Comment: What's the page structure? Where are the js scripts included, is it header/footer? Are the scripts included in sync/async mode? I think your question boils down to a particular page optimization problem so it would be nice to see an URL or a page sketch with a similar structure to check how Chrome schedules resources loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in cases involving performance optimization, you really want to [create an A/B test](https://blog.bufferapp.com/how-buffer-ab-tests) to determine which one you should do. There really is no cookie cutter answer for image preloading that applies to everybody as a best practice.

One of the biggest tenets of a favorite book of mine, [Lean Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449368425), is use to A/B tests to prove or disprove a HIPPO (highly paid person's opinion). Certain opinions carry a  lot of weight, both in your organization and on the internet. Because of their importance and reputation, their opinions veer towards the realm of fact, even though it may not be.

The practice of measuring performance empirically is also touted by another book I love which deals with performance tuning - [Code Complete 2nd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) In that book, McConnell gives several code examples where you would expect one piece of code to be optimal, but in fact, it performed poorly (see chapters 25 and 26). One of his key points is that *you should always test a performance optimization*. *If it isn't worth testing, it isn't worth writing the "highly performant" code in the first place*. McConnell's premise doesn't just apply to his low level coding examples, but to high level decisions such as preloading images above the fold as well.

I can also attest to the importance of A/B testing at a professional level. I used to work on Amazon's SEO team and we A/B tested everything. The fact of the matter is that you never really know how customers will respond to something. Nobody can predict customer behavior - not even Jeff Bezos - and you really need to back up your hypothesis with real data to prove or disprove the validity of what you're doing.

Even though you can find multiple blog articles and online sources discussing whether preloading is better or not, you don't really know whether that will work for you until you've done it. Different people have different servers with different performance characteristics and different network topologies, etc. You just don't know which way is better *for you* until you have the data. If you launch your A/B test and find that find that your repel rate goes up when preloading, then you know that you have to dial back your treatment and return to your control. If however, you find that customers don't get bored waiting and click through at a higher rate than before, then you have a winner and you dial up the treatment - deleting the control code entirely after a period.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The article is wrong about those statements. Preloading is used by the developer because he already knows those assets are needed on a page. Preloading is not a "hint". Prefetching is more in line with what he states, that you are telling a browser that it's possible the asset may be needed.

If an image is above the fold, then you know it will be needed, and that is exactly what prefetching is for.

[Addy Osmani of Google](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf)

> preload is a declarative fetch, allowing you to force the browser to
>   make a request for a resource without blocking the document’s onload
>   event.

Answer (score 0):

I would use rel="preload" for images only if they are to be found in css, javascript that will led to a bottleneck in the render of the page at a later time, if user driven events will request the image and it will have detrimental impact in user experience or if you are experiencing any flows due to this large image in the rendering of the page.

I understand your image is above the fold, and if it's to be found in the source code from the beginning I would let browser prioritize what to download first.
On the other hand you could always A/B this change and see if it works for you.